# Where do numerical solvers for differential equations fail?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am about to begin working on a numerical differential equation solver that uses heuristic optimisation methods (like [evolution strategies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution_strategy) or [differential evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_evolution)) to approximate a solution. However, since such methods can not guarantee global convergence their only "raison d'être" are differential equations that are numerically hard to solve.

What could be some examples of such problems?

**Edit:** 
The starting point for my work is this [Ph.D. Thesis: Solving Differential Equations with Evolutionary Algorithms by José María Chaquet Ulldemolins](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/684d/6c3c09ef050bb641d7d259dbb0c86e13aa5f.pdf).

The optimiser generates approximated solutions, that are represented as a sum of shifted and distorted Gaussian Kernels.

Especially interesting is the comparison performed in chapter *5.3.3 Comparison of DESCMA-ES with Numerical Methods*, which compares the optimiser technique against a Runge-Kutta and an “simple explicit” method. This comparison is done on the Poisson Equation and the Wave Equation. It seems that the optimisation scheme is somewhat competitive, at least it reaches roughly the same residual error. Obviously, the classical methods are way faster.

Comment: Could you give an example where your solver strategy goes right? With a representative overview of intermediate steps? // In general it is the stiff ODE and BVP that are difficult to solve numerically, almost by definition.